# Row_number in SQL

Tags: sql

I have this table "triggerTable"

| trigger | date | isError |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2021-02-16 04:08:12.810 | 0 |
| b | 2021-01-31 04:09:22.977 | 1 |
| c | 2021-02-10 04:15:34.740 | 1 |
| c | 2021-02-16 04:16:06.037 | 0 |
| d | 2021-02-12 04:15:34.740 | 0 |
| d | 2021-02-13 04:16:06.037 | 1 |
| e | 2021-01-24 04:15:34.740 | 0 |
| e | 2021-01-31 04:16:06.037 | 0 |

I need to have for each trigger the latest date and if isError(1) or not isError(0). If the trigger has failed (even NOT recently) I need to have that row.

How can i have this output in SQL Script?

| trigger | date | isError |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2021-02-16 04:08:12.810 | 0 |
| b | 2021-01-31 04:09:22.977 | 1 |
| c | 2021-02-10 04:15:34.740 | 1 |
| d | 2021-02-13 04:16:06.037 | 1 |
| e | 2021-01-31 04:16:06.037 | 0 |

Thanks

Comment: *If the trigger has failed (even NOT recently) I need to have that row* - If a trigger has multiple isError = 1, do you want the earliest, latest, or all?

Comment: The lastest date for `c` is `2021-02-16 04:16:06.037` and not `2021-02-10 04:15:34.740`.

Comment: @forpas: "*If the trigger has failed (**even NOT recently**) I need to have that row.*"

Comment: @PM77-1 Then what is the point of this: *I need to have for each trigger the latest date and if isError(1) or not isError(0).*

Comment: @forpas : I read it as: "This is the rule, but it has an exception". I agree 100% that it's somewhat 
 ambiguous.

Comment: @PM77-1 also the expected result for `d` is the latest date with is Error = 1 and not the previous row with isError = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` with an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "trigger"
                                   ORDER BY isError DESC, date DESC) rn
    FROM triggerTable t
)

SELECT "trigger", date, isError
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The logic above will first attempt to return the latest record in error.  Should no records be in error, it would then default to returning the latest record not in error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select trigger,
       coalesce(case when isError = 1 then date end,
                max(date)
               ) as date,
       max(isError) as isError
from t
group by trigger;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX()` and `FIRST_VALUE()` window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT trigger,
       MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY trigger) date,
       FIRST_VALUE(isError) OVER (PARTITION BY trigger ORDER BY date DESC) isError
FROM triggerTable
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ad9e285c2fd29fd1e8d5589319961ae2).
Results:

| trigger | date | isError |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2021-02-16 04:08:12.810 | 0 |
| b | 2021-01-31 04:09:22.977 | 1 |
| c | 2021-02-16 04:16:06.037 | 0 |
| d | 2021-02-13 04:16:06.037 | 1 |
| e | 2021-01-31 04:16:06.037 | 0 |